# Kile preview in same window

Tags: mac, viewers, kile

I cannot get the view I had on Kile on my Windows machine earlier-the editor on the left and pdf viewer on the right. I am using Kile on a Mac. Whenever I click on quickbuild it opens the pdf in an okular separate window. If I click on pdflatex it creates a pdf file (as it should).

How can I get the viewer in my Kile window (as it originally was!). I am using KDE 4.14.3

Comment: I am bumping this..

Comment: Adding comments will not bump a question I'm afraid. Edits (like the tag-edit I just did) will do that however.

Comment: You probably used Kile 3, the current beta version, which features the in-window preview. Kile 2 (current stable) has no integrated windows.